# Comparing two custom objects

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, comparison, icomparable

```
public class Filter
{
    public int A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
}
```

What is the best way, to compare two `Filter` objects according with sometimes one, and sometimes all properties?
I mean I have `Dictionary<Filter, string>` and I need find all `KeyValuePairs` compatibile with used filter, e.g:

```
var f1 = new Filter(){A = 1}
var f2 = new Filter(){A = 1, Start = DateTime.Now, End = DateTime.AddHour(2)}

var dict = new Dictionary<...>()
dict.Add(new Filter(){A = 1}, "asdf");
dict.Add(new Filter(){A = 1}, Start = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1), "qwerty");
```

Now usigng `f1` I'd like find both `KeyValuePairs`, but using `f2` I'd like to find only first KVP, because of `Start` in second object doesn't fulfill condition `Start` + `End` from `f2` (it is outside the scope)

**EDIT**
Dictionary is outside of the scope of this question. It has to be. I need only mechanism of the comparing. I don't create dictionary to do it. I need it to store some data important for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
    IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<Filter, string>> DoIt(Dictionary<Filter, string> dict, Filter f)
    {
        return dict.Where
            (d => 
                (f.A == null || d.Key.A == f.A) && 
                (f.B == null || d.Key.B == f.B) && 
                (f.Start == null || f.Start < d.Key.Start) /* && Condition for End */);
    }
```

I think the condition is not exactly what you wanted, but you'll probably be able to figure it out from here...

Comment: Nice solution, but what if all properties are null? Now it doeasn't find any item.

Comment: So change the detail lines to (f.A == null || d.Key.A == null || d.Key.A == f.A). This way the item matches if either the filter property or the item property is null.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the `IComparable` `interface` to achieve what you need?

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.aspx for more details.

Comment: I know I can use it, but quite don't know how to use it in my example

Answer (score 0):

If you need to compare by multiple criteria, one `Dictionary<Filter, string>` will not be enough. You can supply a custom `IEqualityComparer<Filter>` when instantiating it, but it will only allow you to define a single comparison criteria.

The point of the dictionary is to allow fast lookup by a certain key, and you won't be able to benefit from this if you want your key to change.

You can either:

1. Create a new dictionary instance for each criteria you are planning to use, and pass the appropriate `IEqualityComparer<Filter>` implementation, or
2. Use a plain `List<Tuple<Filter, string>>` and then filter it using `IEnumerable.Where`.

Answer (score 0):

First. You cannot use dictionary for this. Dictionary only works when you have one way to compare keys. And that is through GetHashCode and Equals overrides of said key object.

If you want to compare two objects, you can implement an [IComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icomparer.compare%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) class, that has parameters on which will compare different properties.